# Trying to find records with the maximum of averages (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with an producer and product table and I'm trying to find the producer(s) with the most expensive products on average. Basically I've got to find averages for each producers products then find the producers with the most expensive averages, in which there can be more than one producer with the most expensive average if they have the same average.

I've attempted with the code below but don't understand why its not working out?

Forget to mention this is for SQL.

EDIT:Forgot to say that the result should only display the most expensive averages

```
SELECT producerId, average 
FROM (SELECT producerId, AVG(productPrice) AS average 
      FROM product NATURAL JOIN producer 
      GROUP BY producerId) AS averages 
WHERE MAX(average)
```

Example:
producerID | average

```
1      |    10
2      |    8.5
3      |    10
4      |    9
5      |    8
```

Result:
producerID | average

```
1      |   10
3      |   10
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: `SELECT producerId, average 
FROM (SELECT producerId, AVG(productPrice) AS average 
      FROM product NATURAL JOIN producer 
      GROUP BY producerId) AS averages ORDER BY average DESC` should do the work ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos thank you worked for me :) Do you know how to only get the higest values on there own

Comment: @GordonLlinoff I'm using mysql sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get 3 most expensive producers, use query like this:

```
SELECT producerId, average
FROM (
    SELECT pr.producerId, AVG(pr.productPrice) AS average
    FROM product AS pp INNER JOIN producer AS pr ON pp.producerId = pr.producerId
    GROUP BY pr.producerId
 ) AS T
 ORDER BY average DESC
 LIMIT 3;
```

For further information, please see the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: @JakeM-B, it is possible to get 3 most expensive producers. Have you testeed my solution?

Comment: @JakeM-B, i added `<create_relationship_here>` because i was sure that you know how to join 2 tables. See this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: @MaciejLosyeah I see what you mean so I changed it to a natural join and it worked thank you but I need it so it only limits the most expensive averages with a limit that can change and adapt

Comment: @MaciejLosyeah Yes It produced the top 3 highest thank you but I need it so it only limits the most expensive averages with a limit that can change and adapt. For example, for the example above, using the code it showed the averages 10, 10 and 9 but I only want 10 and 10 to show up. I know you can just change the limit to 2 but I need it so it would change automatically so that if there were 3 most expensive averages one day it would only show the 3 and if there were 5 MEA's another day, it would only show the 5 without me editing the code

Comment: So, see my comments to Gordon Linoff's solution. You need to return all MEA's which meets your criteria. Well, you need to use ranking function, such as `dense_rank`, which is unavailable in MySQL, but you can write custom `dense_rank` function using variables. Follow the link i provided there.